# Hiding Table Rows Based off selections in 2 drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, show-hide

I am hoping that someone here will be able to assist me, I am trying to create a list of applications and servers that can be filtered through the use of 2 drop down lists  (due to there being over 100 rows worth of data in the table.

So far I have got the table being filtered off either or the Application Name or the Server Function, what I want to get working now is that the table filters based off BOTH selections.

So currently if I pick APP1 off the first drop down it will show all entries for APP1, however if I try to select DB Server it will show ALL applications that have DB Servers instead of just showing APP1's DB Servers.

I am unable to provide the body/contents of the table due to company policy but I have provided the first row at least which would have the headers.

I cannot access jfiddle or anything like that to give a working example as it is blocked by the company I work for.

Hopefully the information I have provided will be enough.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#application").on("change",
               function(){
                   var appName = $(this).find("option:selected").html();

                   $("table tr td:first-child").each(
                       function(){
                           if($(this).html() != appName){
                               $(this).parent().hide();
                           }
                           else{
                               $('#titles').show();
                               $(this).parent().show();
                           }
                       });
               });

$("#function").on("change",
               function(){
                   var functionName = $(this).find("option:selected").html();

                   $("table tr td:first-child").next().each(
                       function(){
                           if($(this).html() != functionName){
                               $(this).parent().hide();
                           }
                           else{
                               $('#titles').show();
                               $(this).parent().show();
                           }
                       });
               });
               });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Select Application"">
<strong>Select Application</strong><br>
<select id="application" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="">APP1</option>
    <option value="">APP2</option>
    <option value="">APP3</option>
    <option value="">APP4</option>
    <option value="">APP5</option>
    <option value="">APP6</option>
    <option value="">APP7</option>
    <option value="">APP8</option>
    <option value="">APP9</option>
    <option value="">APP10</option>
    <option value="">APP11</option>
    <option value="">APP12</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<div title="Select Server Function"">
<strong>Select Application</strong><br>
<select id="function" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="">DB Server</option>
    <option value="">Automate Job Server</option>
    <option value="">Web Server</option>
    <option value="">Application Server</option>
    <option value="">Database & Application Server</option>
    <option value="">Citrix Server</option>
    <option value="">Inbound/Outbound Server</option>
    <option value="">COMMS Server</option>
    <option value="">WEBFARM Servers</option>
    <option value="">WAS Instances</option>
    <option value="">APP/Web Server</option>
    <option value="">Autosys</option>
    <option value="">Qlik Sense Server</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<table style="width: 733.38px;" class=">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 20px;" id="titles";>
<td style="width: 147px; height: 20px;"><strong>Application Name</strong></td>
<td style="width: 162px; height: 20px;"><strong>Function</strong></td>
<td style="width: 256px; height: 20px;"><strong>Server Name</strong></td>
<td style="width: 138.38px; height: 20px;"><strong>ENVIRONMENT</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 20px;">
<td style="width: 147px; height: 20px;">APP1</td>
<td style="width: 162px; height: 20px;">DB Server</td>
<td style="width: 256px; height: 20px;">ServerName</td>
<td style="width: 138.38px; height: 20px;">PROD</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 20.5px;">
<td style="width: 147px; height: 20.5px;">APP1</td>
<td style="width: 162px; height: 20.5px;">App Server</td>
<td style="width: 256px; height: 20.5px;">ServerName</td>
<td style="width: 138.38px; height: 20.5px;">COB</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 20px;">
<td style="width: 147px; height: 20px;">APP2</td>
<td style="width: 162px; height: 20px;">DB Server</td>
<td style="width: 256px; height: 20px;">ServerName</td>
<td style="width: 138.38px; height: 20px;">UAT</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 20px;">
<td style="width: 147px; height: 20px;">APP3</td>
<td style="width: 162px; height: 20px;">DB Server</td>
<td style="width: 256px; height: 20px;">ServerName</td>
<td style="width: 138.38px; height: 20px;">PROD</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you add some sample records?

Comment: I have added in some sample records as requested, had to make it generic due to company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some condition. The second dropdownlist match is not enough, you first check second dropdownlist match.
I have add second condition like that in if block.

```
$("#application").find("option:selected").html() != $(this).prev().html();
```

Full code:

```
$("#function").on("change",
               function(){
                   var functionName = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
                   $("table tr td:first-child").next().each(
                           function(){
                               if($(this).html() != functionName || $("#application").find("option:selected").html() != $(this).prev().html()){
                                   $(this).parent().hide();
                               }
                               else{
                                   $('#titles').show();
                                   $(this).parent().show();
                               }
                           });
                     });
               });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had thought it would need to be something to do with the IF statement in the second function but for the life of me I could not figure it out. If I added something similar into the first functions would it work out the same so say for e.g. when I first start I pick App1 and it filters all App1 then I pick DB server and it works as expected would I then be able to change App1 to App 2 without needed to reselect the server on the second drop down?

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: You can change code for similar conditions. For example when selected "--Select--" item, show all records.